Why does this not generate an response?
I used a youtube Tutorial and a lot of research + Help to write this and I don't know why it is not generating an Answer. Maybe it could be the model I chose but at this time I tried I thin 4 or 5 models.
Here's the Code I've written:
import os
import time
import pyaudio
import playsound
from gtts import gTTS
import speech_recognition as sr
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM
import torch 
import uuid


huggingface_token = "ACCES TOKEN (I just deletet it for StackOverflow)"  

lang = "en"


tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("cognitivecomputations/dolphin-2.8-mistral-7b-v02")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("cognitivecomputations/dolphin-2.8-mistral-7b-v02")


def get_audio():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone(device_index=1) as source:
        print("Listening...")
        audio = r.listen(source)
        said = ""

        try:
            said = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(said)

            if "Jarvis" in said:
               
                input_ids = tokenizer.encode(said, return_tensors="pt")

                attention_mask = torch.ones_like(input_ids)

               
                output = model.generate(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id, max_new_tokens=40)  
                print(output)
                generated_text = tokenizer.decode(output[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

               
                speech = gTTS(text=generated_text, lang=lang, slow=False, tld="com.au")
                file_name = f"welcome_{str(uuid.uuid4())}.mp3"
                speech.save(file_name)
                playsound.playsound(file_name)

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Exception: {str(e)}")

    return said


while True:
    get_audio()

I really have no clue why it is not generating anything, and btw it really eats up all my ram, which is another problem I should look into.
